# Displaying AngularJS content within Views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-view, angularjs-ng-include, ng-app

When I use the following static HTML with views, everything works as I expect it would, shown here:
https://embed.plnkr.co/MJYSP01mz5hMZHlNo2HC/

Now what I am asking, is how do I properly get this angular-ui accordion working properly within the ng-view?

See the accordion I am trying to use here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/1ZWBsbO6sQRnZ7CpPrdz?p=info

And my test plunker here, showing that the HTML shows up in the view, but it lacks JS functionality:
https://plnkr.co/edit/I3myvfH5KUkpfV1aWh72?p=info

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.7" data-semver="1.5.7" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-route@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

<body ng-app="Test">

    <div ng-include='"header.html"'></div>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <div ng-include='"footer.html"'></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have obvious problem. Did you check error in console?

Comment: I do see I have 24 console errors, which has me struggling in figuring things out

Comment: Here is my original plunk, now free of console errors:
https://plnkr.co/edit/W0PVu0CSIH3ymnzt6Iol?p=preview

And then the accordion free of console errors:
https://plnkr.co/edit/W0PVu0CSIH3ymnzt6Iol?p=preview

I guess I just need help understanding, or figuring out how to put the accordion into the ng-view, if that makes sense? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a `controller` with the name(PageCtrl) you defined.

```
app.controller('PageCtrl', [function(){  
 // Your business logic
 alert("In am controller"); 
 }])
```

Comment: Am I to add something specific to the page controller? 

see my plunk updated here

https://plnkr.co/edit/I3myvfH5KUkpfV1aWh72?p=info

Comment: @Abuborey : Yes you did. From  **doc**  ::  _Controller fn that should be associated with newly created scope or the name of a registered controller if passed as a string_.